# How can I convert the result of this Python code to a number of seconds for speed calculations later?

Tags: python

I would appreciate it if you could help me create a few lines of code that change the answer into a number of seconds stored as an integer in a variable.

```
import datetime

def get_dt():
    a_raw = raw_input('Enter time a. Format: HH:MM:SS ')
    b_raw = raw_input('Enter time b. ')

try:
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a_raw, '%H:%M:%S')
    b = datetime.datetime.strptime(b_raw, '%H:%M:%S')
    print (b - a)
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid format!"
    get_dt()

get_dt()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, folks, there's no need to be nasty. Any advice would help

Comment: `b-a` is a `timedelta` object. Check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). There should be a way to get the number of seconds elapsed from that.

Answer (score 1):

Not having a Python 3 installation on my machine I converted your code to Python 3 with the following changes:

- `raw_input` became `input`
- `print` became `print()`

Additionally I fixed passing the values from one function to the other.

In order to get the time difference in seconds you can apply [`.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) such as `b-a` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import datetime

def get_dt():
    a = input('Enter time a. Format: HH:MM:SS ')
    b = input('Enter time b. ')
    return a, b

def calc_seconds():
    a, b = get_dt()
    try:
        a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%H:%M:%S')
        b = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, '%H:%M:%S')
        delta_secs = (b-a).total_seconds()
        print(delta_secs)

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid format!")      
        calc_seconds()

calc_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

In actual fact, I managed to do it by just adding 
.totalseconds() 
after 
time = b-a

Comment: Isn't this just what albert wrote yesterday?

Comment: If my answer worked for my, please tick it in order to mark you question as solved. Please don't post your own answer to your own question if there is an correct answer from someone else since SO is not a forum but a Q&A-platform.